# xwiki docker container: ERROR DefaultExtensionLicenseManager - Failed to load license file at

Tags: docker, xwiki

I'm running the xwiki docker container with docker swarm and the xwiki container keeps randomly crashing. This is the docker-compose configuration:

```
  xwiki:
    image: xwiki:lts-mysql
    environment:
      DB_DATABASE: ${XWIKI_DB}
      DB_USER: ${XWIKI_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${XWIKI_PASS}
      DB_HOST: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./xwiki:/usr/local/xwiki
    networks:
      - web
      - mysql-net
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1.00'
          memory: 1024m
```

The following stacktrace keep popping up, does anyone know what is going on here?:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.xwiki.extension.internal.DefaultExtensionLicenseManager.initialize(DefaultExtensionLicenseManager.java:94)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.InitializableLifecycleHandler.handle(InitializableLifecycleHandler.java:39)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:365)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:451)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:201)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getDependencyInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:406)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:355)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:451)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:201)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:189)
  at org.xwiki.extension.repository.internal.local.LocalExtensionStorage.<init>(LocalExtensionStorage.java:91)
  at org.xwiki.extension.repository.internal.local.DefaultLocalExtensionRepository.initialize(DefaultLocalExtensionRepository.java:100)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.InitializableLifecycleHandler.handle(InitializableLifecycleHandler.java:39)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:365)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:451)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:201)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getDependencyInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:406)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:355)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:451)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:201)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getDependencyInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:406)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:355)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:451)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:201)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:189)
  at org.xwiki.container.servlet.XWikiServletContextListener.contextInitialized(XWikiServletContextListener.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4764)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5222)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1184)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1932)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1094)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:476)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
2023-01-02 20:28:14,183 [main] ERROR DefaultExtensionLicenseManager - Failed to load license file at [null] 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.xwiki.extension.internal.DefaultExtensionLicenseManager.initialize(DefaultExtensionLicenseManager.java:94)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.InitializableLifecycleHandler.handle(InitializableLifecycleHandler.java:39)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:365)
  at org.xwiki.component.embed.Embeddable
```

It always crashes at some point with this error message but also works until this error message appears.

Comment: This seems to have been a problem with tomcat 9.0.70 and should be fixed in newer versions, see https://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI-20470 and https://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XDOCKER-261  A newer version of the docker image should fix this.